# PHP REST API Webservice with images correct use?

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I am new to developing webservice,  my idea is to build a REST API based on PHP. 
Which make possible to CRUD images files e.g. images/test.jpg.

Is possible to get images over a REST webservice? If yes, then how?
Or is a webservice only for json responses provided?

I prefer approach without a framework, because i want to learn.

My routes:

```
// GET
/api/images  # Get alle images
/api/images/1 # Get images based on primary key

// PUT
/api/images/1 # Update images based on primary key

// POST
/api/images # Add a new image

// DELETE
/api/images/1 # Delete images based on primary key
```

## JSON Response example

```
  /api/images/1
```

## Version the image file itself stored phyisical on webservice project(www.example.com).

```
{
    "filename": "example.jpg",
    "filepath": "www.example.com/images/example.jpg",
    "htmlAlt": "Example Image",
}
```

or be better this version

## Version the image itself stored phyisical on frontend project(www.example-frontend.com).

```
{
    "filename": "example.jpg",
    "filepath": "images/example.jpg",
    "htmlAlt": "Example Image",
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to just return the URL for the image in JSON, which is the common thing to do in a REST API (return JSON). But if that's not good for you, you could try and get the actual text representation of an image. Although they're images, computational speaking, they're a bunch of data that you can send/receive like any other text. Maybe convert it to base64 or something.

Comment: Your recommendation just return the url for the image over JSON sounds plausible to me.
Means that, a frontend requests the REST Webservice API and get the JSON with URL of an image and must over additional request(cURL) to get the image file?

Comment: Well, to better discuss the subject, you'd have to think more about the users of your API. From my side of the table, I don't have server-side languages consuming my API and I can assert that. Which means when a framework such as AngularJS consumes my API, they can just append the URL to the HTML and it will just work. Now if you know that your API will be consumed by server-side languages, maybe you should give it some more thought.

Comment: You should scrape the webpage and extract img tags containing the image.

Comment: You are right, i am should to more focus, how to use the api from the user, in my case is that a frontend based on react.js.

I should say, the frontend is provided over JSONs Responses by the REST Webservice.

The image file itself stored phyisical on the frontend and the REST Webservice handle the exchange with the database.

Answer (score -1):

> Is possible to get images over a REST webservice?

Yes.

> If yes, then how?

You make a GET request to the URL which represents the image. The server sends back an image.

(Said server might also support PUT requests to upload new images, DELETE requests to remove them, and so on).

> Or is a webservice only for json responses provided?

A webservice provides whatever kind of data its author wants to provide.

Comment: I guess what you tried to say is that the OP could specify (from the server) that the response is a content-type image? I haven't thought of that when he asked about it, but if that's your answer, I think you should consider helping out more on how to go about handling the subject, provided that the question is PHP specific.